# Bootstrap Tooltip on Filestyle input element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, bootstrap-file-upload

Is there a way to attach a Bootstrap [Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) to a [Filestyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/) input element?  Something that would appear like this when hovered over:

[image: Filestyle with tooltip]

I've tried the following without success:

```
<input data-toggle="tooltip" title="Attach file" type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" data-buttontext="" data-iconname="glyphicon-paperclip">
```

Here is a link to a [JSFiddle session](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffdahl/admvx689/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work for the small `button` version by doing the following.

First, apply a class to your `filestyle` input:

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle apply-tooltip" data-input="false" data-buttontext="" data-iconname="glyphicon-paperclip"/>
```

Notice the `.apply_tooltip` class? Next, loop over elements of that class and assign a couple attributes to their sibling `<div>` elements (which are generated by `filestyle`):

```
$('.apply-tooltip').each(function(){
    $(this).siblings("div").attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
    $(this).siblings("div").attr("title", "Attach File");
});
```

Lastly, call your `$([data-toggle="tooltip"]).tooltip()` function as you normally would. This will activate the `tooltip` on the generated `<div class="bootstrap-filestyle input-group">`.

The reason you need to do this is that `filestyle` hides any elements that is uses to generate the custom input fields. Because of this, the `tooltip` was being activated correctly, but on a hidden element.

Here is a modified version of your JSFiddle showing this in practice:

http://jsfiddle.net/admvx689/1/

I'll see if I can get the other two working as well. Hope that helps for now though!

Edit

It actually works for the larger inputs too, you just have to hover over the right section (the button on the right)

http://jsfiddle.net/admvx689/3/

Comment: You are a genius!  Thank you so much.  I also removed the 'data-toggle="tooltip" title="Attach file"' from the input element to remove an additional tooltip that was popping up over to the right.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Glad you got this to work for you. Cheers!